# Difference between v2.18 and v2.22.0 of Maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I configured surefire v2.18 to exclude tests in packages like `e2e.com.mycompany.myapp` but not like `com.mycompany.myapp.e2e` and it was working but if I use v2.22.0 I get a different behavior: both are excluded.  Is it a bug?

My configuration is:

```
<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>e2e/**</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

I also tried with:

```
<configuration>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>e2e/**/*Test*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

How can I get the same behavior with the new version?  I'm using Maven 3.3.9.

Comment: Checked the docs https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#excludes

Comment: Sure, also the more specific page https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html but the new regex-based syntax is just an option and the old one should work: they says "An include/exclude pattern can be an ant-style path expression, but regular expressions are also supported".

Answer (score 0):

You could go through following link which explains enhancements made with v2.19 onwards for exclusion and inclusion of tests:

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

**Following is brief snapshot captured from above link for inclusion and exclusion of packages and classes:**

[image]

**Following link explains release notes for v2.22:**

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12317927&version=12343425